# What is, Context, serviceFactory and Service in Plugin CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been woking with CRM since seven months ago. I still don't know what is, for what is used and why those variables.

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{

     Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
     serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

     IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

     IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
}
```

I've searched for answers without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN provides a nice set of articles starting from [Understand the Data Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx).

In short, here it goes:

1. `IPluginExecutionContext` is where all the contextual information is brought to your code. `InputParameters` and `OutputParameters` member contain for example the record the plugin is being fired upon, the pre- and post-image, the handled message (*The actual data depends on how you registered the plugin: pre VS post, the exact message, online or offline...*)
2. `IOrganizationService` object allows you to query the Organization Service. Most common usage scenario is CRUD operations (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete : beware of deadlocks).

Comment: serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId) : what if one user belongs to more than one organization?

Answer (score 1):

**IPluginExectionContext:**

1. Defines the contextual information passed to a plug-in at run-time. Contains information that describes the run-time environment that the plug-in is executing in, information related to the execution pipeline, and entity business information.
2. The execution context is passed to a plug-in at run time in the System.IServiceProvider parameter of the Execute method. You can obtain the context from the service provider as shown in the following plug-in code.
   // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.

**IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(
                IPluginExecutionContext));**

**IOrganizationService Interface:**
Provides programmatic access to the metadata and data for an organization.